# How to check GPS service is enabled or not in IONIC FRAMEWORK

Tags: service, ionic-framework, gps

I am developing an application which has a facility to track user location for that I used Cordova Geolocation plugin but, before that have to check GPS is enable or not.

Answer (score 4):

In the Cordova Geolocation plugin there is the method:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                     [geolocationError],
                                     [geolocationOptions]);
```

That is all you need. If geolocation is disabled, the `geolocationError` function is called. The [docs say](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#android-quirks) that on android you need to specify a `timeout` in the `geolocationOptions` in order to make the `geolocationError` function be called. So you would have to do it like so:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                     [geolocationError],
                                     {timeout:3000});
```

To call the `geolocationError` function after not receiving a geolocation (= geolocation turned off) after 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your help @niklas

Comment: But what if the app is not active or in background?