# How to check GPS Disabled or Enabled on ionic freamwork?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

How to check GPS Disabled or Enabled on ionic framework? please give me some example.please help

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006454/use-phonegap-to-check-if-gps-is-enabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check GPS service is enabled or not in IONIC FRAMEWORK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130807/how-to-check-gps-service-is-enabled-or-not-in-ionic-framework)

Comment: sir give me an example

Comment: can i send my whole code through mail?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ionic-native `Diagnostic` it is simple and easy to implement.

> https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

to use this, first install it

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/diagnostic
```

import in file

> import {Diagnostic} from 'ionic-native';

and then use it.

In my case it was like:

> let isGPSenabled = Diagnostic.isLocationEnabled();

or as in example :

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAvailable(function(available){
    console.log("Location is " + (available ? "available" : "not available"));
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
```

or you can also find it out in a simple way via navigator like :

```
 if(navigator.geolocation){ // success }
```

hope this helps you!

Comment: Sir am using ionic v1

Comment: simple add plugin via https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin
then use it as my second example defined : 
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAvailable(function(available){
    console.log("Location is " + (available ? "available" : "not available"));
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});

Comment: if (navigator.geolocation) {
  alert("your location is on")
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
        var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
        $scope.lat = p.coords.latitude;
        $scope.long = p.coords.longitude;
    });
} else {
    alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
}

Comment: i want to check that first check the gps enable or not after the map is load into the div section.

Comment: please  give me an example

Comment: use it like : 
 if(navigator.geolocation){
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((location) => {
                           console.log('location',location);
})}
else { gps unavailable}

Comment: sir when i apply this code and build then the app page is blank like white

Comment: please sir give me your Email id